# Why is indexing necessary on histograms?

Tags: image, image-processing, histogram, fpga

I'm currently reading the book Design for Embended Image on FPGAs chapter 7 about histograms, and my big question is why during the construction of the histogram is necessary to index the output of the counters? Here's a image of this [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHXzD.png)

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly is the question? Why are the multiple counters? Why do they have indices? The photo shows a MUX, the index is used to select which counter value to output on count.

Comment: That's exactly what I couldn't understand! Thank you!